# Python pydantic-xml how to load recursive model's

Tags: python, xml, pydantic

I try to read an xml with something like a Folderstructure and getting an error.

```bash
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

XML simplified

```xml
<Folder Name="rootfolder">
    <Folder Name="subfolder">
        <Folder Name="subsubfolder"></Folder>
    </Folder>
    <Folder Name="subfolder">
        <Folder Name="subsubfolder"></Folder>
    </Folder>
</Folder>
```

link to [pydantic-xml](https://github.com/dapper91/pydantic-xml)

I did some similar things with a json file and native pydantic over there it worked

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Folder(BaseXmlModel, tag="Folder"):
    name: Optional[str] = attr(name='Name')
    folder:  Optional[List[Folder]] = element(tag='Folder')

Folder.update_forward_refs()
```

Comment: What is the code that produces the error? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The issue is resolved by a new version of pydantic-xml. With the version V0.30 recursive models are supported.